# Inheriting from Theme.AppCompat*

Tags: android, android-theme

Currently working on migrating to ActionBar in the support libraries. Currently trying to migrate my old themes to inherit from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` but it isn't going very smoothly.

It is fine if I apply the theme in the manifest as such:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.fitsby.LoginActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
</activity>
```

But I get a runtime error, stating that LoginActivity(subclass of ActionBarActivity) must  have a theme which inherits from Theme.AppCompat, when I do the following:
in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>   
</style>
```

and in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.fitsby.LoginActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</activity>
```

Any ideas why that is happening? I do not see a problem, since AppTheme clearly inherits from one of the AppCompat Themes.

Comment: Do you have multiple values folder(like for different API levels)? If yes, did you used that style in all of them?

Comment: That ended up being it, thanks for that, was solely responsible for backend dev on the project, but just recently took over design work from a team member who decided to leave, so little things like this are causing a bit of a headache. If you would like to change your comment to an answer I will mark that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have different `values` folder in your application, for different API levels, make sure that each of those themes from the folders extend from the required `Theme.AppCompat.*` themes.